# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Завтра я не смогу сдать свою работу, так как у родителей появились
> дела(,) и они попросили помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая перед союзом И не ставится:

*Завтра я не смогу сдать свою работу, так как **у родителей появились дела и  они попросили помочь.***

Запятая не ставится **между однородными придаточными**  со значением причины.

В этом случае **общим элементом**, связывающим придаточные предложение, является главное предложение.

Одинаковый подчинительный союз (в данном случае союз ТАК КАК) может повторяться или не повторяться.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) **запятая не ставится**: *Отец мой говорил, **что** он не видывал таких хлебов **и что** нынешний год урожай отличный* (Акс.); *Чудилось, **будто** корчуют сразу весь лес **и** выдираемые из земли корни и сама земля стонут и вопят от боли* (Фед.)